# Minimum No. of JK FlipFlops needed to design a user defined counter

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter, ripple-counter

We want to design a synchronous counter that counts the sequence 0−1−0−2−0−3 and then repeats. The minimum number of J-K flip-flops required to implement this counter is :

**My doubt:**
We can design this  with 3 flipflops if we use combinational logic and the **output is taken from that computational logic** we can get the possible output.My doubt is ,can it can be called as counting(if we use the o/p of combinatioanl logic)? or we should only consider the output from the Flipflop for counting/output(I mean the state of the flipflops)?

**Possible Solution:**
       Let output of 3 flip flops be S1, S2 , S3. Take them through below circuit.
[image]

[image]

So if we take **B C as final output we can generate 0->1->0->2->0->3**.

So I think it is possible with 3 flip flops.

*Reference*:Vinayk:www.Gateoverflow.in

Comment: Original post:
https://gateoverflow.in/39670/gate-2016-1-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as a state machine. Naively (and rightfully), it has 6 states, one for each input. 6 states require 3 bits to encode. 3 bits = 3 flipflops.

Comment: So can we use the output of a combinational logic or is it possible to derive directly with the FF outputs for counting?

Comment: You can realize it very easily. Consider a mod-6 counter (counting from 0 to 5) made from whatever you want (in your case 3 JKs). And then just add a combinatorial logic to it's output, translating `0, 2, 4` into `0`, and `1,3,5` into `1,2,3` respectively.

Comment: So here we are using the output of the combinational logic right?.Can it be done in a counter?.I didn't found any reference for the output of a counter(counting) being fetched from combinational logic!.So I want to confirm that my approach is right.

Comment: That's an OK approach.

Comment: Any standard reference for this approach?.Because, at last the proof matters.I didn't get one.

Comment: This is a standard, straight-forward [Moore state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) implementation approach. Output is a combinatorial function of the state memory.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Can you draw required circuit using 3 J-K flip-flop, please? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219480/the-minimum-number-of-j-k-flip-flops-required-to-implement-this-counter-is?lq=1